# How to convert an Erdas training set to .csv?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, r, erdas-imagine

I am working with Erdas Imagine's Signature Editor to perform maximum likelihood classification.  I need to use the same training set created in Erdas for other classification using R.  Is there a way to extract the raster band pixel values under the .aoi polygons and export that information to a .txt or .csv?  I am looking for the same functionality as the ArcGIS [Sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002v000000.htm) tool where the individual raster band pixel values are extracted underneath points and written to a table (e.g. Figure 2).  Alternatively, is it possible to export the signature editor table (i.e. including R,G,B,NIR bands and the class label) to a .csv?  Any workarounds on how to integrate Erdas's signature editor with the analytical functionality of R would be very helpful.

For example, I need the functionality of the signature editor

Figure1
[image]

Yet I need to convert these values to a format that I can read into R.  Note that I need all four bands of the input image along with a class ID (i.e. grid code).  This table was generated in ArcGIS.

Figure 2
[image]

Comment: Can you upload a sample of your sig file? I'd like to have a play around with the file, but don't have erdas installed in the office. Thanks.

Comment: @sgrieve I've uploaded the .sig to a file sharing service:http://wikisend.com/download/372268/maxlikesig.sig

Comment: Thanks, I've not had any joy pulling any data out from the sig file. I can't find any documentation on the format, so I am going at it blind unfortunately. Hopefully someone else will have some more luck.

Comment: I have been using this software (http://www.gdargaud.net/Hack/BinToAscii.html) to try and reverse engineer the sig file, but its trial and error to get the data in the correct format.

Answer (score 2):

It has been a while since I used ERDAS, but I believe you can export .aoi to ASCII. In ERDAS, Utilities>Export pixels to ASCII. ?? Then you could load that into a CSV file. You can also convert your .aoi file to .shp, which you could then use with the ArcGIS sample tool you mentioned.